# Error NPM start on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have problem about start npm (ReactJS)

when i run terminal `npm start`

It's show error:

> ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server /index.js Module not found: Error: Can't
>   resolve '/index.js' in '/home/truc/TrucTran/dev/workspace/reactapp'  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
>   webpack/hot/dev-server /index.js webpack: Failed to compile.

**Content file package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "reactapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  }
}
```

**Content file webpack.package.js:**

```
var config = {
   entry: '/index.js',

   output: {
      path:'/home/truc/TrucTran/dev/workspace/reactapp/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Please help me about this issue !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, it can't find your `index.js` entry file. Create your `index.js` file and rerun npm.

Comment: Well, that's all I can tell you, since that's literally what the error says, and I don't have enough information to really jump to other conclusions. I'd recommend double checking either where your `index` file is located or double checking your config.

Comment: Thanks stinodes so much :) I will review entire project